# how do I install qemu on my bq Aquaris M10?

Tags: ubuntu-touch, virtualization, qemu, aquaris, bq

I am trying to install scrivener (windows, or Linux) on my bq Aquaris m10 tablet.  The problem is that scrivener is only written for amd/x86 hardware, and my tablet is arm.  The good news is that this has been apparently been accomplished on other arm base systems (Raspberry pi, and arm base Chromebooks) using a program called qemu... Scrivener can then be run as a native Linux beta, or though wine.

I have looked at the various tutorials and web-casts on the subject, and so far none of them have helped.  They all seem to be skipping key steps, or simply showcase the finished product, without actually telling you how to do it your self.  I've tried to follow what instructions I could find, but as I said, they either don't translate to my particular device, or they're missing key steps to make it work.  If anyone knows how to do this, I would appreciate the help.

Comment: I doubt you could get reasonable performance emulating an x86 processor on the M10 (and even less on the Raspberry Pi). Could you point to those tutorials you found?